# osgi: Bundle is not active

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, soapui, manifest.mf

just another question for my osgi project. I get this error code:

> !SESSION 2015-10-26 10:50:01.671
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_60 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=de_DE Command-line arguments:  -dev
>   file:C:/Users/Dennis/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/delicomFirstOSGIPlugin/dev.properties
>   -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console
>
> !ENTRY de.delicom.testosgi 4 0 2015-10-26 10:50:02.318 !MESSAGE
>   FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
>   Error loading bundle activator.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   de.delicom.testosgi.Activator.java cannot be found by
>   de.delicom.testosgi_1.0.0.qualifier   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
>     ... 11 more Root exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   de.delicom.testosgi.Activator.java cannot be found by
>   de.delicom.testosgi_1.0.0.qualifier   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-10-26 10:50:02.322 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   de.delicom.testosgi_1.0.0.qualifier [11] is not active.

My Manifest looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Testosgi
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.delicom.testosgi
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: de.delicom.testosgi.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: . ,
 soapui-4.0.1.0.jar,
 xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar,
 xmlbeans-xpath-2.6.0.jar,
 src/
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

The external jar's i've added to Buildpath and Classpath. They are also in the referenced libaries.

Anyone have an idea? Thank you

Comment: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.delicom.testosgi.Activator.java "  Why does it say ".java" in there? Should just be a class name. Your manifest seems okay as posted. Maybe an old version still deployed/cached?

Comment: it is my first installation of osgi. I get also an "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet." error. Do you have any idea what happend there?

I don't know why there is ".java" in there.

Comment: Search all your files for "Activator.java".

Comment: Yes there is an Activator.java file in my workspace in the src folder. Sorry i'm a comple noob with osgi :/

Answer (score 0):

**>org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error loading bundle activator**
this is typical run-time error if you forget define "bin/" (or "target/..")  folder 
in your project: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF :

```
Bundle-ClassPath: target/classes,  **<<<---- here is it !**
 libs/log4j-1.2.16.jar,
 libs/slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar,
 libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar,
 libs/commons-io-2.4.jar
Bundle-Activator: com.senatov.smapperApp.Activator
```